# How do i use a lookup in excel to return a value from a third column, if criteria are met in 2 other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset which has columns as follows. It shows me the number of people (in the time columns) that are in the room (resource) on date.

Sample Dataset:

[image: Sample Dataset]

I am attempting to return the following.

Sample Result:

[image: Sample Result]

Essentially, im trying to search my dataset, and return the number of people in each room, at each time and date, in a more digestible manner.

Apologies if i havent explained myself correctly, and i havent really worked out how to use this forum properly yet, but i'm hoping to use the collective to help with this problem. I'm not an excel newbie, but i can't seem to get the right mix of match/index/v/hlookups to do what i need!  Thanks :)

Ok, so updating based on NightCrawler's assistance, still getting random errors at 1 and 4pm! any tips?

[image: timing errors]

Comment: you could update the screenshots with actual results that you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved your desired result using this formula. I added another column to get correct dates in each row because i did not want to deal with merged cells (see image).

```
=SUMIFS(OFFSET($C$2:$C$7,0,MATCH($D11,$C$1:$L$1,0)-1),$A$2:$A$7,$B11,$B$2:$B$7,E$10)
```

Drag the formula to all cells

[image: Revised Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Nightcrawler. This is doing exactly what i need it to, albeit with a couple issues. I actaully have 10 time periods i'm trying to reference, and when i drag it out, (ie from C1 to L1, 9am - 6pm) and from P2 to P12, it works for all timeslots except 1 and 4pm: i get an #N/A, and excel keeps throwing up a circular reference :(. FYI - i have extended the match from C1:E1 to C1:L1

Comment: Is your data and the output table in the same sheet? I extended the data columns to L1 but still getting all results. No error. I have revised my answer.

Comment: i've added a screenshot of what i'm experiencing in my original post, thanks so much for your help sofar - do you reckon you could take a look? Thanks :)

Comment: I am using the exact same formula as yours, even the same ranges (although i don't have data unitl row 7602. I don't get an error. Can you check the values of 1pm and 4pm, whether they match or not.

Comment: try to use jus `=MATCH(P16,C1:L1,0)` to see if that results in an error. also you can evaluate the formula to see whatpart is giving the error

Comment: Revised Screenshot

Comment: Yeah ok, weird. for some reason when i change the values to 1pm  and 4pm in Column P (or im assuming any other arbitrary value), and do the same across C1 - L1, it works. Must be something weird behind the values. All sorted - works just using shorthand for all the cells, which is good enough for the reporting. Thanks SO MUCH!!! Really appreciate your help. Will save this one for future record :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method you could use

Select your data. Goto Data Tab. Under Get & Transform, click From Table. In the pop-up check *My Table has headers* -> ***OK***

A window(Query Editor) will pop-up.

[image: Query Editor]

Select your time columns and in the transform tab click Unpivot Columns. This is what you will get

[image: Unpivot data]

Notice that the time column is now renamed and there is a new colunm "value".Now select your resource column and click on Pivot column (Transform tab). For Values Column, choose Value(the new column that was added) . In advanced options, make sure "Sum" is selected.

[image: Options]

Click ***OK***. you should have your result. In the Home tab click close and Load.

[image: Final]

The rows may not be in the correct order, coz you are using it as a string. You may use numbers for better sorting.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately excel 2013, and to install plugin i need admin rights, which at work i don't have :(